# How to get comments from a worksheet as a pandas dataframe after reading in with openpyxl and

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I can get the data from an Excel worksheet as a dataframe by using :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'test.xlsx',data_only=True)
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
```

But how do I get the comments from each cell into a dataframe? The worksheet cells might not all have any comment with them, but resulting dataframe must have the same dimensions as the original worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list of the [`comment`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html?highlight=comment#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.comment)*s* and pass it to the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) construtor.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)

comments = pd.DataFrame([
    [cell.comment.text if cell.comment else None # or whatever
     for cell in col] for col in ws]
)
```

Output :

```
print(data, comments, sep="\n"*2)

   0  1
0  A  1
1  B  2

             0            1
0  1st comment         None
1         None  2nd comment
```

---

```
data.shape == comments.shape # gives True
# (2, 2) == (2, 2)
```

Used input (`test.xlsx`, *I tried to mock your configuration*) :

[image]